# invalid bytes32 value - Maker Contract Call

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying to call the Maker CDP Contract manager smart contract.

I want to get the information from this public mapping in the contract.

`mapping (bytes32 => Cup)  public  cups`

and should return a mapping:

```
    struct Cup {
        address  lad;      // CDP owner
        uint256  ink;      // Locked collateral (in SKR)
        uint256  art;      // Outstanding normalised debt (tax only)
        uint256  ire;      // Outstanding normalised debt
    }
```

Where bytes32 should be a bytes representation of the CDPId.  They have a python implementation that passes a value to this mapping from a function that looks like this.

```
def int_to_bytes32(value: int) -> bytes:
    assert(isinstance(value, int))
    return value.to_bytes(32, byteorder='big'
```

I've tried this:

```
myContract.methods.cups(web3.utils.fromAscii("5")).call(
    function (err, res){
        console.log(res)
    }
)
```

However, I cannot figure out for my life how to pass the proper ID of say 5 to the bytes32 mapping and return the proper output.  Everything returns with 0's even though I know that is incorrect.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web3.utils.numberToHex(13850).substring(2).padStart(64, '0')

This was ultimately the solution that worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this `web3.utils.numberToHex(number)`
or just a string like this `'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005'`